# HTTPS and OpenVPN on port 443 together

Tags: nginx, https, openvpn

until recently I was using lighttpd + openvpn + sslh, to provide both HTTPS and OpenVPN on port 443. But sslh has some significant issues with passing remote IP address to HTTP server and also it does not work well with Gitlab. So I moved to nginx and now I'm trying to achieve the same functionality with OpenVPN as before.

How to configure nginx to handle incomming HTTPS connections and forward unknown connections to OpenVPN?

I know OpenVPN can do this with HTTPS, but it does not solve problems with passing remote IP address to web server (correct remote IP address is more important for web server than for OpenVPN).

Other way around may be like Websockets do, to let OpenVPN to use HTTP upgrade or similar technique, but I haven't found anything about that in OpenVPN documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Nginx is not capable of looking into SSL connections to determine the protocols used to further forward the connection to either an http/https upstream, or a VPN.

It can handle any arbitrary TCP streams now (and load-balance the connections without looking into payload), but unless you have more than one port or more than one IP address, you'll have to continue to depend on your [`sslh`](http://ports.su/net/sslh).

Comment: Yes, this is what I think, but there must be another way around.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not done in the enterprise setting (outside of people trying to bypass the corporate firewall), so, no, nginx is by design not designed to be doing these things; nginx main focus has always been efficiently dealing with large-scale web-sites and large-scale projects; doing https and openvpn on a single ip/port is not it.  Also, in order for something like http upgrade to work, you'd have to have client support, and why would presumably off-the-shelf browsers send upgrade headers for your web-site all of a sudden? The best way out would probably be to figure out sslh